# Цвет иконок в выезжающем меню

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Добрый день. Я использую `NavigationView` в своём проекте. В строчках меню, я указываю свои икноки белого цвета, но когда я запускаю приложение на эмуляторе или девайсе, то мои иконки становятся серыми. Пробовал указывать для них бэкграунд `transparent`, но это не помогло. Помимо этого, моя иконка почему-то растягивается. Подскажите, что я делаю не правильно? 
Вот мою меню:

```
  <item
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:id="@+id/menu_info"
        android:title="@string/info_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_i"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />
```

Вот скрины, как я хочу сделать и как получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Серый цвет для них это стандарт `NavigationView`

```
mNavigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
```

Сделайте так: `mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);`

И пошло поехало:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/primary" />
        <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</selector>
```

Можно еще попробовать так: `mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);` и

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ...
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/black" 
    ... />
```

Для того, чтобы картинка не была растянутой нужно делать ее соответствующей для каждого размера экрана т.е:

```
 1. drawable-xxhdpi: 144x144 
 2. drawable-xhdpi: 96x96
 3. drawable-hdpi: 72x72
 4. drawable-mdpi: 48x48
```

Начните [отсюда](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html) изучение

Comment: Спасибо, я разобрался уже, что цвет автоматом ставится серый, вот это помогло `app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"`. 
Но остается вопрос, почему моя иконка растягивается?

Comment: @Denis422 вы подгружаете картинку из drawable? если да, то какого она размера?

Comment: @Denis422 обновил ответ

Comment: Да, из drawable. Некоторые иконки нормально отображаются, а эта растягивается. Похоже что из-за размера, те иконки которые меньше в ширине как раз и растягиваются..

Comment: @Denis422 Рад был помочь вам) если ответ помог, то нажмите на голочку слева от ответа:)

Comment: А если у меня иконка 21x21?? Я вообще имею только одну папку drawable, хотя на разных экранах всё более менее смотрится.. Можете посоветовать какой-то ресурс по читать именно по этой теме?) можно и на англ, но только чтобы было хорошо разжёвано)